# What does ^:dynamic do in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've googled for "clojure dynamic" and "clojure dynamic scope" and read over 10 articles and I still don't have a clear understanding of what `^:dyanmic` does.  [I think this article may be answering my question](http://blog.rjmetrics.com/lexical-vs-dynamic-scope-in-clojure/), but the code samples seem to be "missing" so I'm not even sure if it's referring to the same thing I'm confused about.

I'm trying to fix an issue in the [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/master/src/clj_http/client.clj) project but first I have to understand the code.  It has functions defined like this:

```
(defn ^:dynamic parse-html
  "Resolve and apply crouton's HTML parsing."
  [& args]
  {:pre [crouton-enabled?]}
  (apply (ns-resolve (symbol "crouton.html") (symbol "parse")) args))
```

But I don't understand what that `^:dynamic` means/does.  Can anyone explain it to me in a really simple way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is defining the function as being dynamically scoped.

In other words, this allows someone to re-bind `parse-html` in a given function invocation and have that new binding apply only to functions called from that specific invocation.

If `parse-html` were not dynamically scoped then re-binding it would cause the new binding to be seen by any code that uses `parse-html` and not just code that was activated by the function invocation that did the re-binding.

> Dynamic scoping is useful as a substitute for globally scoped variables. A function can say "let current_numeric_base = 16; call other functions;" and the other functions will all print in hexadecimal. Then when they return, and the base-setting function returns, the base will return to whatever it was. 
>   http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DynamicScoping

---

As was pointed out in the comments below, you can't actually re-bind variables that aren't dynamically scoped in Clojure.  If you could, updating a variable that is lexically scoped will impact all code that is executed even if it is running in a different call stack from where the re-bind occurred.

So maybe some pseudo-code will make the difference between dynamic and lexical scope clear.

Example of using a dynamically scoped variable:

```
(def ^:dynamic a 0)

(defn some-func [x] (+ x 1))

; re-binds a to 1 for everything in the callstack from the (binding)
; call and down
(binding [a 1] 
   (print (some-func a)))

 ; a was only re-bound for anything that was called from
 ; within binding (above) so at this point a is bound to 0.
(print (some-func a))
```

**would print:**
2
1

Example of a lexically scoped variable:

```
(def a 0)

(defn some-func [x] (+ x 1))

; re-binds a to 1 for everyone, not just things that 
; are in the callstack created at this line
(set-var [a 1]  ; set-var is a made up function that can re-bind lexically scoped variables
   (print (some-func a)))

; a was lexically scoped so changing it changed
; it globally and not just for the callstack that
; contained the set-var.
(print (some-func a))
```

**would print:**
2
2

Comment: Cool, this is a pretty good answer but I'd feel like I'd understand it even better if you showed me some sample code using ^:dynamic and demonstrated the difference you've explained.  Would you mind doing that?

Comment: If `parse-html` were not dynamically scoped, then re-binding it would be illegal.